# Update table after adding rows jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I have a button with class "addrow" to add rows to this table like below:

```
$(".tdclass").keyup(function() {
  \\doing something
});

var counter = 5;
$(".addrow").on("click", function() {
  var newRow = $("<tr>");
  var cols = "";
  cols+='<td>something</td>';
  newRow.append(cols);
  $("#mytable tr:last").prev().after(newRow);
  counter++;
});
```

the button works and I can add `tr` to the table but there is one problem. The problem is after adding new row, functions under `$(".tdclass").keyup` does not work at the same time and I need to make some changes to other cells to activate those functions for new rows. I think I need to update/refresh table after adding new rows but I'm not sure.

Comment: after you are done with your table try removing the keyup function and re-adding it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the event handler for the keyup function and then re-add it once you are done composing your table.

Something like this could work:

```
$( ".tdClass").unbind( "keyup" );
```

then once you are done composing your table you can re-add it.

```
$(".tdclass").keyup(function() {
  \\doing something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can go this way:
Change this:

```
$(".tdclass").keyup(function() {
  \\doing something
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".tdclass", function() {
  \\doing something
});
```

This will help avoid doubling in the code and handle dynamic added new elements in the table. Hope it will helps